# Three circles of radii 9, 4 and 1 tangentially touch each other. Find the radius, r, of the small circle formed which touches all the three circles.

Tags: geometry

[image]

> Three mutually tangent circles with radius $9,4$ and $1$ are given. How can I determine the radius of the small circle, which is tangent to these three circles?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem ,

Comment: What do you call the length ?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Use [Descartes' Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133589/4-spheres-all-touching-each-other/3133927#3133927)

> $$\bigg(\sum _{d=0}^{4}k_d\bigg)^2=2·\sum_{d=0}^{4}k_d^2$$
>   where $k_d$ are the curvatures of the circles

In your case, we obtain $$k_1=\frac19\qquad k_2=\frac14\qquad k_3=\frac11$$ Thus, in virtue of Descartes' Theorem

\begin{align*}&\bigg(\frac19+\frac14+1+\frac1{r_4}\bigg)^2&&=2\cdot \bigg(\frac1{81}+\frac1{16}+1+\frac1{r_4^2}\bigg)\\\iff &\bigg(\frac{49}{36}+k_4\bigg)^2&&=2\cdot \bigg(\frac{1393}{1296}+k_4^2\bigg)\\\iff &\ldots\end{align*}

---

You can *alternatively* (which might also be simpler) use this corollary from Descartes' Theorem

\begin{align*}k_4&=k_1+k_2+k_3+2\cdot \sqrt{k_1k_2+k_2k_3+k_1k_3}\\ &= \frac19+\frac14+1+2\cdot\sqrt{\frac1{36}+\frac14+\frac19}\\&=\frac{49}{36}+2\cdot \sqrt{\frac{14}{36}} \end{align*} Finally

> $$r_4=\frac{1}{\frac{49}{36}+2\cdot \sqrt{\frac{14}{36}}}=\frac{36}{49+12\cdot\sqrt{14}}=\frac{36(49-12\sqrt{14})}{49^2-12^2\cdot14}=\frac{1764-432\sqrt{14}}{385}\approx \bbox[fuchsia,5px]{\color{white}{0.38}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Use Heron's formula:
$$S_{ABC}=S_{ABD}+S_{ACD}+S_{BCD} \iff \\
\sqrt{14\cdot 4\cdot 9\cdot 1}=\sqrt{(10+r)\cdot r\cdot 1\cdot 9}+\sqrt{(13+r)\cdot r\cdot 9\cdot 4}+\sqrt{(5+r)\cdot r\cdot 4\cdot 1} \iff \\
2\sqrt{126}=\sqrt{r}(3\sqrt{10+r}+6\sqrt{13+r}+2\sqrt{5+r}) \Rightarrow \\
r=-\frac{36}{385}(12\sqrt{14}-49)\approx 0.38.$$
WA [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20sqrt%7Bx%7D(2sqrt(5%2Bx)%2B6sqrt(13%2Bx)%2B3sqrt(10%2Bx))%3D2sqrt(126)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that I will be better at using the Descartes theorem to solve the question as the other user has answered.

Comment: You think, therefore you are. Good luck.